# GPS on simulator and Onboard SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

Using simulator on DJI assistant 2 for my M210, the input for GPS position on simulator work well, and DJI GO 4 app on my tablet displays desired position.
However, in Onboard SDK, whenever I subscribe to GPS position of the drone, using this line:

`Telemetry::TypeMap<TOPIC_GPS_FUSED>::type subscribeGPosition =
                vehicle->subscribe->getValue<TOPIC_GPS_FUSED>();`

`subscribeGPosition` return the different position than the one I put in the simulator. Its always return: `lat:0.188360`, `lng:1.861927` (?) why is that?

I need the returned position on my subscriber to be at the one I put in the simulator. The reason is I am testing with waypoint mission, and if I put positions way further than the the returned position, it won't start.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but getValue returns the lat and lo in Radians, while you put it in Degrees

Comment: Just convert them